# FInd The (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) values of a text when the text is rotated (90, 270) degree in the PDF page (PDF BOX)

Tags: pdf, pdfbox, text-rotation

Hi I have an Use case to find the (x1, y1) (x2, Y2) values of the text in a page when the text is rotated 90 and 180 degree.

I am able to find these values when the text is at 0 degrees and 180 degrees.

So the idea is to use the PDStreamengine class from the PDFBOX and overriding the method from the same class and using them to find the x1,y1,x2,y2 values ,

For the above code i am getting the values properly when the text is 0 and 180 degree.

for the following [pdf](https://acrobat.adobe.com/link/review?uri=urn:aaid:scds:US:89832b02-9064-313d-9701-ad76ab8ed4c1)

i.e when the text is 0 degree
(x1 =31 , y1 =726 , x2 =122 , y2 = 744 )

when the text is 180 degree
(x1 = 122, y1 = 744, x2 = 31, y2 = 726)

i am getting the above values.

but when i rotate the text to 90 degree, Rotated text [PDF](https://acrobat.adobe.com/link/review?uri=urn:aaid:scds:US:73a20772-2ed4-35b1-b208-39391e89ec0d),I am getting the values as (x1 =22 , y1 =660 , x2 =22 y2 = 740)

**Here we can see Both the x1 and X2 Values are same.**

how can we Find the X1 and X2 values of a text when it is rotated 90 degree and 270 Degree ?

I got above mentioned values by using the following [code snippet](https://wtools.io/paste-code/bDhr)

I have also thought of using the TextPosition "printWord" method so, will that be a solution find the x1,y1,x2,y2 values.

```
x1 = Double.valueOf(text.getYDirAdj());
y1 = Double.valueOf(text.getXDirAdj());
x2 = x1 - text.getHeight();
y2 = y1 + text.getWidth();
```

And any code snippet with the example will be helpfull.

Thanks
Tejas

Comment: In your calculations you added to `showText(byte[])` you didn't fully multiply the text matrix with the current transformation matrix, you just applied a part of it. In case of horizontal text the part you ignored eventually is 0, so your ignoring it is harmless. In case of vertical text, though, the part you ignored is non-0. Thus, you had better execute the full matrix multiplications and pick the required values from the result of that multiplication.

Comment: Have a look at the `DrawPrintTextLocations.java` example, maybe you can use parts of it.